# Dynamic link in css stylesheet with PHP variable

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a dynamic page template for wordpress (which means it has to work at least 4 different domain without changing anything like links etc.) and I added a custom css link like this:

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/page-food.css">
```

I can reach the server home in a variable like `$home_path`. Or the theme main folder like `$theme_path`. So is there any possible way to add the href a PHP variable?

I mean

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="$theme_path/css/page-food.css">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add php start and end tags there

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?=$theme_path?>/css/page-food.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wordpress css call in daynamic path 

<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/fonts.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```